# Ruby on Rails generate controller giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-generate

I'm currently trying to generate a controller in rails with the command:

```
rails generate controller Songs index upload delete
```

But I get the error:

```
/Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require': /Users/lucasdobbins/rails_projects/mp3app/config/application.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      :secret_access_key  => 'fmbDA3...
       ^
/Users/lucasdobbins/rails_projects/mp3app/config/application.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
from /Users/lucasdobbins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Ive also tried just using:

```
rails generate
```

But get the same result, anyone have any idea has previously been working.

Comment: it looks like an error in your application.rb file. can you post the code for it here as well? Around line 21 as the trace says...

Comment: Usually this is a simple thing to fix, it's probably just an if or a do without an end.

Answer (score 2):

Check line 20 or 21 of your config/application.rb for an unclosed parentheses. That's what the error message says.